# Is it posible to have Jstree contextMenu with Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, contextmenu, jstree, http-redirect

Is it possible to have a Mvc4 Link (`http://localhost:59446/TierManagement/CreateTier`) in the contextmenu of jsTree, which will take me to new view (CreateTier page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of that item in context menu, just redirect to the required page using

```
document.location.href="<!--your link goes here-->";
```

the code would be

```
action(obj){
document.location.href="<!--your link goes here-->";
}
```